# drop in fread: misses repetitions of col name (data.table R)

Tags: r, data.table

I've got a file with a bunch of filler columns (named, of course, `filler`) that I'm trying to read with `fread`.

I'm using the `drop` argument, but it only drops the first (presumably left-right, but this is irrelevant) instance it encounters; I want it to get rid of all of these.

Quick example:

header of `.csv`:

```
id,first_name,last_name,filler,birth_year,filler,position,filler,wage
```

`names(dt)` from using `drop` in `fread`:

```
id,first_name,last_name,birth_year,filler,position,filler,wage
```

Further, if I just try:

```
DT <- fread("file.csv", drop = rep("filler", 5L))
```

I get an error:

> Error in `fread(paste0(substr(tt, 3, 4), "staff.csv"), drop = rep("filler",`  : 
>         Duplicates detected in drop

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read the first line of the file with `scan()`, and then use that data as the `drop` indices in `fread()`

```
## example text for fread()
x <- "id,first_name,last_name,filler,birth_year,filler,position,filler,wage
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
## read the first line and find the filler
f <- scan(text = x, what = "", sep = ",", nlines = 1) == "filler"
## pass to fread()
fread(x, drop = which(f))
#    id first_name last_name birth_year position wage
# 1:  1          2         3          5        7    9
```