# Returning values in mtcars r data frame as a table

Tags: r

I am new to r and am playing around with the mtcars data frame. I am trying to find the mileage and horsepower of only those cars with 4 cylinders. Here is what I have:

```
ifelse(mtcars$cyl==4,mtcars[,c(1,4)],1)
```

I'm fairly sure that this statement gets the correct values, but it returns the values in the form of a list. Is there a way that I can return the values as a table? (i.e. car names in the left-most column and value headers in the first row?)

Comment: this? `mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4, c(1,4)]` A table is a specific data structure in R. So be sure that you do not mean a standard spreadsheet type layout.

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(x<-mtcars,keep.rownames=T)[cyl==4,.(hp,mpg)]`

Comment: even if you don't use `data.table`, you should get in the practice of referring to columns by name: `mtcars[mtcars$cyl==4,c("hp","mpg")]`

Comment: @MichaelChirico It's better to know both as sometimes you will only have a numeric index to subset by. Or the latter.

Comment: @MichaelChirico your code does not produce the desired output. OP requested row names.

Comment: @plafort I can only think of [one instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886591/drop-in-fread-misses-repetitions-of-col-name-data-table-r) I ever needed the numeric indices and that was pretty boutique--but I guess it is useful to keep in mind that it is possible.

Comment: @MichaelChirico agreed

Comment: @plafort should be `setDT(x<-mtcars,keep.rownames=T)[cyl==4,.(rn,hp,mpg)]`, sorry about that.

Comment: ` object 'rn' not found` Do you have a devel version?

Comment: Yes, `1.9.5` via [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). The `keep.rownames` argument of `setDT` may be new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4, c(1,4)]
```

or

```
with(mtcars, mtcars[cyl == 4, c(1,4)])
```

or

```
subset(mtcars, cyl == 4, select = c("hp", "mpg"))
```

Notice that inputting `c(1,4)` is equivalent to `c("hp", "mpg")` as another commenter mentioned.